# Generate random time considering a condition

Tags: excel, formula

I'm trying to generate a random time within a range of two times, Considering 2 conditions, The generated time has to be ahead from the range start by 1.5 Hrs minimum and 3 Hrs maximum. The increment threshold has to be 5 minutes.

Example :

```
                     Start        Stop
Range              16:00:00     20:30:00
```

A valid generated value can be `17:30`, `17:35`, `17:40` ...till `19:00`.

I've tried the `=RANDBETWEEN(A2*60*24,B2*60*24)/60/24` formula, But I can't force it to only generate by 5 minutes threshold, or consider the above 2 conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do it in 5 minute steps go for `*24*12` as there are 12 x 5 minutes in one hour...
the range is always 1.5h simply run

```
=RANDBETWEEN(0,18)/12/24
```

now add the 1.5h to the starting time and also add the formula (more obvious with `TIME`:

```
=A2+TIME(1,30+RANDBETWEEN(0,18)*5,0)
```

shorten to:

```
=A2+TIME(1,RANDBETWEEN(6,24)*5,0)
```

**EDIT**
fun solution:

```
=TIME(0,RANDBETWEEN(TEXT(A2,"[m]")/5+18,TEXT(A2,"[m]")/5+36)*5,0)
```

Comment: That did it perfectly! :) Thank you so much, Dirk.

Answer (score 2):

```
=ROUND(RANDBETWEEN(60*24*(A2+TIME(1,30,0)),60*24*(A2+TIME(3,0,0)))/5,0)*5/24/60
```

[image]